# Disable "requested without authorization" feature?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Sometimes when debugging locally, I will get a popup similar to this for various resources:

[image]

How can I completely disable this feature?

Comment: Does enabling [this option](https://i.imgur.com/L7shNSf.png) help?

Comment: Looks like it may have.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can enable the [**Allow unsigned requests**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsPIC.png) option.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Go to
`File >> Settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Debugger`

then check the `Allow unsigned requests`. (Tick mark that)